# LVM - Recovering from partition table corruption

Tags: partition, lvm

I accidentally deleted a partition on a physical disk that was involved in an LVM system. I tried using testdisk's analyse feature to find the LVM partition, but it couldn't locate it. Should I invest in a deep scan, or is there an easier way to locate the partition and re-add it to the partition table? Actually just getting the file system back by any means would be great.

To be clear, an LVM partition is intact somewhere on the disk, but I don't know where.

The disk is partitioned with GPT

Comment: Does this help any? http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/recovering.html

Comment: The LVM partition starts somewhere arbitrary on the drive, so I can't find the superblocks by formula

Comment: Have you tried doing pvscan?

Comment: pvscan requires the LVM partition to exist

Comment: It depends on how you "deleted" the partition. If you "accidentally" clobbered the partition table, you could try `gdisk` _**recovery and transformation options**_ and from within the advanced menu _**use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)**_ If you deleted the partition using gdisk, the backup GPT will be of no help

Comment: Didn't know about `gdisk`, thanks. I decided to reinstall, but for interest's sake, I did clobber the partition table. I was surprised at how hard it was to fix. With normal ext partitions, recovering from that would be very easy with testdisk. Suppose you've just got to know the one tool that can save you